# Checking, compare data value and addclass

Tags: jquery

I try to check which  element  is currently hover and adding class to div with the same data value

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Złącze słuchawkowe" data-id="#dialog1"
   class="single-image-item single-image-item-1" href="#" data-value="Headphones Plug">
     <i>1</i>
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Złącze słuchawkowe" data-id="#dialog2"
   class="single-image-item single-image-item-1" href="#" data-value="Charging Port">
     <i>1</i>
</a>

<div class="single-hot-spot-item" data-value="Headphones Plug">
     <span class="hot-spot-single-item hot-spot-item-1">1 </span>
     <p class="hot-spot-item-description">Złącze słuchawkowe</p>
</div>
<div class="single-hot-spot-item" data-value="Charging Port">
     <span class="hot-spot-single-item hot-spot-item-1">1 </span>
     <p class="hot-spot-item-description">Złącze słuchawkowe</p>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You want to use `Headphones Plug` as a css class? You'd need to convert the name first, though

Comment: I want to use data-value, when I mouseover on <a> element with data-value="Headphones Plug" I want add hover class to div with the same data-value

Comment: but `Headphones Plug` would be two css classes (`Headphones` and `Plug`), not one. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Maybe I said it wrong. I want to add class "hover" to div with the same data-value which i hover on <a> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to keep your `<div>` indexed by the data-value attribute, then use `jQuery.hover(fn)` to toggle.

```js
(function($) {
  // building this can be one-liner, but lazy
  sections = {}
  $('div').each(function() {
    sections[$(this).data('value')] = this;
  });
  $('a').hover(function(event) {
    const section = sections[$(this).data('value')];
    $(section).toggleClass('hover', event.type == 'mouseenter');
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.hover {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Złącze słuchawkowe" data-id="#dialog1"
   class="single-image-item single-image-item-1" href="#" data-value="Headphones Plug">
     <i>1</i>
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Złącze słuchawkowe" data-id="#dialog2"
   class="single-image-item single-image-item-1" href="#" data-value="Charging Port">
     <i>1</i>
</a>

<div class="single-hot-spot-item" data-value="Headphones Plug">
     <span class="hot-spot-single-item hot-spot-item-1">1 </span>
     <p class="hot-spot-item-description">Złącze słuchawkowe</p>
</div>
<div class="single-hot-spot-item" data-value="Charging Port">
     <span class="hot-spot-single-item hot-spot-item-1">1 </span>
     <p class="hot-spot-item-description">Złącze słuchawkowe</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
       var aVal=$(this).attr('data-value');
       $('.single-hot-spot-item').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover'); 
        if($(this).attr('data-value')==aVal){
          $(this).addClass('hover');
         }
       });

    });
```

Comment: Something like that, but not exactly. 
I hover element <a> with data-value="HEADPHONES PLUG" and it should addclass("hover") to element with the same data-value.